# Using underscores with thymeleaf th:href

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I am using thymeleaf on the frontend of the application.
I have one anchor tag with th:href pointing to URL with many underscore as follows

```
<a th:href="@{https://abc/xyz___data_system_/theme_something}"></a>
```

Because there are underscore in the URL I get

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as expression: "_data_system_/theme_something"
```

I am not sure how to solve this error.

Comment: Does this escape needs to be in single quotes

Comment: Actually - my apologies. The notes in my previous comments (now deleted) are not relevant here (they are for literal text, not text in a `@{...}` URL. I was too hasty. In fact, I cannot recreate that `TemplateProcessingException` using the example you have provided in your question. It works correctly for me. Can you provide a [mre] in your question?

Comment: (Also, for the example in your question, you could just have used a regular HTML link: `<a href="https://abc/xyz___data_system_/theme_something"></a>` because there are no Thymeleaf variables being used.)